# Azure Functions Errro - Could not load file or assembly System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, .net-framework-version

I am working on Azure Functions and these are created in .Net Core version 3.1 whereas the other libraries are written in .Net Framework 4.8. While executing the functions, I am getting following error -

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: XXXXXX. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'XXXXX' threw an exception.). XXXX.Service: The type initializer for 'XXXXX.Service.XXXXX' threw an exception. XXXX.Service: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the libraries reachable ? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563417/5853218

Comment: Can't find this nuget package from nuget official website. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/5.0.0-preview.1.20120.5

Comment: I've hit the same issue today 
`: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

When I look in the bin dir I'm not seeing the DLL. I can't find it in my packages dir either but it says been installed.

Comment: Same Error. There is no package with that specific version and there are no explicit reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the issue by adding the _FunctionsSkipCleanOutput to the project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package version exists. From this it seems that there is no package version in which you reported an error, check this link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/5.0.0-preview.1.20120.5

Click Version History, and you will find:

[image]

Comment: This is not the answer. Azure Functions has A LOT of limitations.
It is an absurd release it in production.